# Pandas data frame to nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have the starting data frame looking like this:

```
my_list = [
    ['Japan', 'Flowers'],
    ['United States', 'Guns', 'yes'],
    ['Japan', 'Sushi'],
    ['South Korea', 'Sunscreen']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=["country", "sector", "flag"])
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I've tried with SO's help to make the dictionary:

```
out = []
for idx, g in df.groupby("country"):
    out.append({"name": idx})
    ids = {}
    for i, s in g["sector"].iteritems():
        ids.setdefault(s, []).append(i)
    out[-1]["groups"] = [{"name": k, "ids": v} for k, v in ids.items()]


out = {"groups": out}
print(out)
```

The result is

```
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "Japan",
            "groups": [
                {"name": "Flowers", "ids": [0]},
                {"name": "Sushi", "ids": [2]},
            ],
        },
        {"name": "South Korea", "groups": [{"name": "Sunscreen", "ids": [3]}]},
        {"name": "United States", "groups": [{"name": "Guns", "ids": [1]}]},
    ]
}
```

The "id" is the number of row from the data frame where the data is located.
But this code does not pick up the flag column.

How can we add it so that whenever flag is not None, it will be picked up like:

[image]

In this case the flag is set to yes.

Comment: What would be the desired output?

Comment: As in the second photo if there is a flag:    {
        "name": "United States",
        "groups":
            [
                {
                    "name": "Guns",
                    "groups":
                        [
                            {"name": "yes", "ids": [1]}
                        ]
                }
            ]
    }, the yes signifies the flag

Comment: HI, what if the flag is None?